# Why can't I paste coordinates in "Enter Map Coordinates"?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-2.6

Using QGIS 2.6.1-Brighton, I am attempting to use the Georeferencer. My data is from NGS datasheets. I copied and pasted the data into a text document. In the "Enter Map Coordinates" dialogue, when I click on the spaces to enter the coordinates, and click "Paste" (having copied the datum from the text document), nothing is apparent. I do not understand why the Paste function is defective in the "Enter Map Coordinates" window. Is this an error, and is there something I can do to paste my data into the spaces?

Comment: I would first verify that the copy made it to the clipboard by pasting to a blank text file or something. If that works, verify that what you're trying to paste is acceptable to where you're trying to paste it (ie only numbers and no letters, or other such mismatches). You could also try using the keyboard shortcut vs right-click vs edit>paste on a menu if there is one. Sometimes one method of pasting will work when others will not.

Comment: also sometimes a newline/carriage return character is included in copied text, so be careful of that... could make it look like there's nothing when really there's a value and a carriage return.

Comment: It was because there were commas in the numerals in the text file. Now I deleted the commas and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Because commas were in the numerals in the text file. Now I deleted the commas and it works!